# Dataset form 5500

Tags: labor

I am curious if form 5500 is included in any current datasets or will be included in the near future. I certainly have a workaround for this, but an API call to the dataset would be much more direct.

Comment: Don, since your question is tagged [labor], I assume you got kicked here from the US DOL website (reason: see [here](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/editing-a-tags-name-wondering-about-us-gov-involvement-just-the-usual)). You have landed on a world-wide site about open data. Can you [edit] your question so it makes more sense to a general audience? I, for instance, have no idea what a 5500 form is.

Comment: Don, were you able to find an answer? currently looking for this